# Cascading of data not happening in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Why am I not getting the logs here? I am attaching the data in the parent and the child group being created should inherit it, right?

Here I am creating a new SVG group, and attaching data, and for every single data unit, I want a group to be created. Please help me finding where I am missing?

Code::

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', 600)
.attr('height', 300)
.data([[20,30],[40,50]]);

var g = svg
.selectAll('g')
.enter()
.append('g');

g.each(function (d, i) {
  console.log(d, i)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your data is in svg, not in g so svg.each will give you results. If you see here in the console https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/7zxmw5nv/ the `__data__ ` is on the svg not on g.

Comment: Ya I am looking to attach so for every g, like first g should have [20, 30], the senond g should have [40, 50]. How to achieve that @mkaran. Any help is appreciated
Update: Thanks for the fiddle. Ya I get you point, but how to achieve the avobe. Because I have a single data: [[20,30],[40,50]]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/qkbqgpkt/ (if you want 2 groups one for each element in data then add your data on g not svg) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> I am attaching the data in the parent and the child group being created should inherit it, right?

They do inherit. You **can** add data to the SVG and get your groups based on it, that's not the problem. The problem here is just two things:

First, for your desired result (*"first g should have [20, 30], the second g should have [40, 50]"*), this should be the data:

```
.data([[[20,30],[40,50]]]);
```

Second, you have to reference the data of the parent to create your `<g>`s:

```
.data(d => d)
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 600)
    .attr('height', 300)
    .data([[[20, 30],[40, 50]]]);

var g = svg
    .selectAll('.g')
    .data(d => d)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

g.each(function(d,i) {
    console.log(d,i)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `.data(d => d)`, nice!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can read in the API: "data [can] be specified as a function. This function will be evaluated for each group in order, being passed the group’s parent datum (d, which may be undefined), the group index (i), and the selection’s parent nodes (nodes), with this as the group’s parent element".