# D3 Data Binding - When to put brackets around data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-binding

I'm looking at multiple D3 code examples similar to this:

```
var data = [1,2,3...];
var blah = d3.selectAll("#blah").data([data]).enter()...;
```

But sometimes I'll see it as this:

```
var data = [1,2,3...];
var blah = d3.selectAll("#blah").data(data).enter()...
```

All the code I've written has been in the second form and I've never had any issue, but I copied a code example online that was in the first form and it did not work when I removed the [].

Can someone explain why it's necessary here and when we should put brackets around what's already an array object?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the code sample you tested use an older version of d3.js?

Comment: Funny enought, the second example (`.data(data)`), despite you saying that you see it "sometimes", is by far the most common one. I provided an answer, but it would be better if you specify the particular situation in which you had to put the extra pair of brackets, so we can give you a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I think your answer helps, but here's the example:

Comment: Sorry I can't edit my previous comment and hit enter too soon:

I think your answer helps, it looks like the example I'm looking at is doing svg = div.selectAll("svg").data([data]);

So if I understand right this means it's binding the entire data array to the svg whereas if you didn't include the brackets it would create data.length number of svg objects and bind each element of the array to a different svg.

Comment: It depends. How are you using this data after you bound it to the SVG? That's the most important detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In d3. the `data()` method accepts three things:

- A function
- An array
- Nothing (when it acts as a getter).

That being said, this is the issue:

In most situations, you can simply pass `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` as the data. So, if you have:

```
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
```

You can simply write:

```
.data(data)
```

However, in some situations, as when an element inherits the data of a parent group, you have to wrap it in an extra pair of brackets (check [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285023/5768908) I wrote). We do that because the child element gets its data as a function, where the parent's datum is passed.

Check this:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

var body = d3.select("body");

var divs = body.selectAll(".divs")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("div");
 
var par = divs.selectAll("p")
 .data(d => d)
 .enter()
 .append("p")
 .text(d => d);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, the same code, with an extra pair of brackets:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

var body = d3.select("body");

var divs = body.selectAll(".divs")
 .data([data])
 .enter()
 .append("div");
 
var par = divs.selectAll("p")
 .data(d => d)
 .enter()
 .append("p")
 .text(d => d);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In the first snippet, 3 divs are created. For each one, a string datum is passed to the paragraphs (d3 will turn each string, such as `"foo"`, in an array such as `["f", "o", "o"]`, and you'll get 3 paragraphs for each div).

In the second snippet just one div is created (since our array's length is just 1), and the entire inner array (`["foo", "bar", "baz"]`) is passed to the paragraphs.